# How to create a new list by pairing the elements on the basis of index from 2 different lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

Example, I have the following lists in Python

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
```

I would need to create a new list C such that the elements should be paired as a separate lists based on their index numbers. i.e., `C = [[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]], [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]]`

I have written a code to that but it is purely structured. Can you please provide if there is any better way other than the below code?

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
D = [a,b,c]
E = [d,e,f]
C = []
list = []


for i in range(len(A)):
    list.append([A[i],B[i]])
C.append(list)
list = []
for i in range(len(D)):
    list.append([D[i],E[i]])
C.append(list)
```

I have to repeat this code if I have multiple cases similar to the above one in my code. Which is poor in structuring.
Can someone suggest any better method for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has a simple solution found in Python's built-in functions,
The 'zip' function takes 2 arguments (iterables) and return a single iterator.
Here is an example code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = list(zip(a, b))
# c -> [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
# if you want the elements to be list instead of tuple you can do
c = [[i, j] for i,j in zip(a, b)]
# c -> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks! for your suggestion. It helps.

Comment: Happy to help! plz upgrade my answer

Answer (score 6):

You can use zip, convert that to `list`

```
list(zip(a,b))
```

which will give list of tuples. If you want list of lists, you can go:

```
[[i,j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in one line.

```
C = [[A[i],B[i]] for i in range(len(A))]
```

Be careful if A and B don't have the same length though!

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip for this

```
c= zip(a,b)
c=list(c)
```

if you convert in set then

```
c=set(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, the following would be efficient.

```py
import numpy as np

A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
a = np.array(A)
b = np.array(B)

c = np.vstack((a, b)).T
print c

C = c.tolist()
print C
```

lower case letters are all numpy arrays, upper case are python arrays